# How to dynamically generate collapsible-set in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic

I retrieve from a php file some headline datas (main headlines, each of them has sub headlines).

The data I receive works fine, but when I want to generate a collapsible-set in jquery (mobile), it doesn't show the beautiful theme... just plain text?!

Here's my HTML file:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-content-theme="d" id="headlinegroup">
```

And here's my javascript file:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "headline_getter.php",
   dataType: 'json',
   cache: false,
   success: function(data1){
   console.log ("debug 2");

   var i = 0;

   var $elements = '';
   $.each(data1[i].main, function() {
          console.log ("debug 3 ");

          $elements += ($('div[data-role=collapsible-set]#headlinegroup').append('<div data-role="collapsible"><h3>' + data1[i].main + '</h3><div data-role="fieldcontain"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="headlinegroup'+[i]+'">'));
          var j = 0;
          $.each(data1[i].sub, function() {
                 console.log ("debug 4");

                 $elements += ('<label><input type="checkbox" name="headlines[]" data-mini="true" value="' + data1[i].mid[j] + '"/>' + data1[i].sub[j] + '</label>');

                 j++;

                 });

        $elements += ('</fieldset></div></div>');
        $elements.collapsible();

          i++;

          }); 
   }
   });
```

I don't really know where the problem is. I've read some thread here at stackoverflow and added the `.collapsible` attribut but it don't work... theres just plain text.

Thanks in advance. Best regards, john.

Comment: Please improve your question by providing some solid examples and asking a specific question. Throwing some random snippets and asking "how?" will not take you anywhere. Also, there are no threads in StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks. I said that the data is shown, but not in the typical jquery collapsible (accordion) theme... it is shown just as plain text!

Answer (score 3):

have you tried to add `.trigger('create')` at the end of every element you append?

Comment: thanks for the answer. i've solved the problem with appending `.collapsible('refresh')` at the end of every element. it's similar to the `.trigger('create')` you've mentioned, but i think i can imagine that i read that this `.trigger` line is an old one and now the new standard is `.collapsible('refresh')`. don't really know if it's right...